# Format Rails Query Strings by removing repitition /clients?ids[]=1&ids[]=2&ids[]=3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In Rails 3.1, how would you go about making a query string appear cleaner and more readable.

For example, the Rails default for a key with multiple parameters in the query string would appear like:
/clients?ids[]=1&ids[]=2&ids[]=3

I want it to appear like:
/clients?ids=1,2,3
or even
/clients?ids=1|2|3

The ids are controlled by a series of links that act as filters for selecting 1 or more options for filtering on some search results.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

The only way you could do it automatically is by monkeypatching something in Rack or Rails. You should avoid doing that as it's going to cause more issues than it solves.

If you have a string that embeds a `|` or `,` then you could have it incorrectly converting data. Or if you only have one entry such as `ids=1` it wouldn't know to convert it into an array with just `1` inside.

You would be better off doing this manually whenever you need to pass an array that needs to be cleaned up. In this case, you would just call `ids.join(",")` when passing it to the router method and `params[:ids].split(",")` to get an array back out.